# Android DrawerLayout with custom Toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

My `Activity` code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Overview overview = new Overview();
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    user.setUserName(intent.getStringExtra("Username"));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.mycontainer, overview)
                .commit();
    }
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navview);
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

// Toggle function for the navigational drawer
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

After adding this line:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

My drawer dissapeared. So all I have left is my actionbar_menu.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity.SecondActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/mycontainer"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/navview"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

So basically, how do I get both my actionbar, my `DrawerLayout` and a custom title to work? I have to disable the `showTitleEnabled` to set a custom title, but it makes my menu dissapear. So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom toolbar layout and include it in your XML instead of `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`

and in your custom toolbar layout put a `TextView`.

Comment: That doesn't get my navigation drawer back. It only adds a new custom title

Comment: You can use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Was missing. This fixes it